# SQL Select Where

Tags: sql, query, select, lógica, where

Preciso fazer um `SELECT` em uma tabela que contém **`ID`**, **`VALOR`**, **`DATA`** e **`NOME`**.

O resultado tem que trazer **apenas** as linhas em que a **foi a maior data** existente.

#### Exemplo:

```
ID    VALOR        DATA        NOME
1      100      22/05/2016     pedro
2      120      22/05/2016     lucas
3      100      21/05/2016     pedro
4      190      21/05/2016     lucas
5      100      21/05/2016     pedro
6      190      21/05/2016     lucas
```

#### Resultado esperado:

```
ID    VALOR        DATA        NOME
1      100      22/05/2016     pedro
2      120      22/05/2016     lucas
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Carlos, tinha tentado algo parecido mas algo estava errado...

Answer (score 8):

Você pode usar a função `MAX` do SQL na sua condição

```
SELECT *
FROM <tabela>
WHERE DATA = (SELECT MAX(DATA) FROM <tabela>)
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer uma subconsulta dentro de um SELECT e utilizar a função MAX que retornar a maior idade. Ou seja, você fará um WHERE onde a comparação com um valor virá de uma consulta SELECT.

```
SELECT id, valor, data, nome
FROM Tabela
WHERE data = (SELECT MAX(data) FROM Tabela)
```

Comment: Regilan, tente trazer respostas diferentes para agregar mais conhecimento, sua resposta provavelmente ficou negativada, mesmo sendo igual a anterior, para desincentivar informações duplicadas. Não negativei sua pergunta, apenas estou dando esse toque para melhorar o nível do fórum. Abraço!